# ggplot2: fix absolute size of ggplot on onscreen device (RStudio plots pane)

Tags: r, ggplot2, size

This feels like the most basic question that must have been answered already, but I have Googled for hours and not found a useable answer.

I will be generating a huge number of 3 inch by 3 inch plots that will all be saved using ggsave(..., width = 3, height = 3, units = "in").  I would like to make sure they always display on screen (in the RStudio plots pane) as 3 inches by 3 inches, so that I can quickly check that they look right before I save them.

But I just can't seem to find a way to do this!  Things I have tried:

1. `egg::set_panel_size` is *almost* it!!  It is great until I, say, add a title to my plot, and then it is only the panel size that is fixed (so the whole plot is then bigger than 3x3).  But the fact that I can fix the sizes of the panels makes me think it must also be possible to do the same thing with the whole plot?  And that is exactly what I need.  (Though even better would be to render the plot as if it were 3in x 3in regardless of the size of the screen, but this would do!)
2. `dev.new` is possible but a bit clunky in that I have to have a separate window open, which makes iterative refinement of my graphics rather slow and painstaking (and also not robust to, say, a silly moment where I accidentally resize it).
3. `cowplot::draw_plot` allows me to set the height of the plot relative to the window size but not (as far as I can see?) an absolute size.

I've tried a lot of other things (e.g. trying to hack the ggplotGrob object) but I can't seem to see a way to do this.  To be clear, this is *not* about saving at the specified size (that bit is easy) it is about generating a rapid preview that will look the same as my ggsaved plot.  Thank you!

dev.new

Comment: You might try out the `camcorder` package, which essentially replaces the preview pane with the graphics device of your choice.

Comment: `ggplot2` has no way to change the size of the graphics pane within the RStudio IDE, so your only option is to avoid using it, perhaps using JonSpring's suggestion of `camcorder` (I don't use the IDE so I don't have an ability to confirm or test other methods).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments -- had Allan Cameron not had a solution that fitted directly into what I have already, this looks like it would have been the way to go.  Never heard of camcorder, I shall be checking it out either way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can programmatically resize the plotting window, but in any case a better solution would be to have the plot drawn in the centre of the plotting window at a fixed size. You can do this by drawing the ggplot to a fixed-size viewport within the plotting window. This will remain the same size and aspect ratio however your IDE is set up.

The following function will allow a ggplot object to be drawn in this format, with dimensions of your choosing:

```r
draw <- function(plot, x_in = 3, y_in = 3) {
  
  grid::grid.newpage()
  
  grid::rectGrob(gp = grid::gpar(fill = "gray")) |>
  grid::grid.draw()
  
  grid::viewport(width  = ggplot2::unit(x_in, "in"), 
                 height = ggplot2::unit(y_in, "in")) |>
    grid::pushViewport()
  
  ggplot2::ggplot_build(plot) |>
    ggplot2::ggplot_gtable() |>
    grid::grid.draw()
}
```

For example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()

draw(p)
```

[image]

If you don't want to have to call `draw(p)` every time, but just have ggplots automatically draw this way during an interactive session, you can do

```r
print.ggplot <- draw
```

after defining the above function.

This results in the following behaviour

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = factor(gear))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I had in mind thank you!!!  I was able to switch this in place of my call to egg::set_panel_size and it does exactly the same thing except it is the whole graph that is fixed rather than just the panel.  No idea how you knew how to do that - pure magic.